# Django- form submitting to the same view and not to desired view

Tags: django, forms, post

My form stopped submitting to the desired view, and submitting to its own view instead.

**URLS.PY:**

```
path('validate_registration', views.validate_registration,name='validate_registration'),
```

**VIEWS.PY:**

```
def user_registration(request):
    print("in reg")
    # populate form
    form = register_form(request.POST)
    print("anonymous form")
    template = loader.get_template('registration.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render({'form':form}, request))


def validate_registration(request):

    if request.POST:
        print("validating")
        #populate form
        form = register_form(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'val_reg.html', {})
```

**TEMPLATS.HTML:**

```
<form class="text-warning text-center rounded pt-2 ps-2 pe-2" method="POST" action="{% url 'validate_registration' %}" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <br/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning mt-5">Register</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</form>
```

The form was working, but after change to the views.py it stopped, which made me shorten its code to few lines only. Even the print "in reg" line doesn't work.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `user_registration` view, you are creating a new form instance with `request.POST` data and then rendering it. This is not standard for a `GET` request scenario. Generally, you'd instantiate the form without data (`form = register_form()`) for a `GET` request, and with `request.POST` data for a `POST` request.

Also, function `validate_registration` in your view, you are populating the form with `request.POST`, but you're not doing anything with it afterward.

If you want to validate the form data, you should check if the form is valid (`form.is_valid()`) and then proceed next.

Try this in your `views.py`:

```
def user_registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = register_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # Redirect to a new URL, or handle the data
            pass
    else:
        form = register_form()

    return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form})

def validate_registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = register_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Process valid data
            return render(request, 'success_template.html', {})
        else:
            # Handle invalid form
            return render(request, 'val_reg.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I changed the code to match your answer exactly. But still the form does not submit to function "validate_registration(request)".

Comment: What happens when you submit the form? What error or issues you can see? Is it going 404?

Comment: it submits to the same page: the "url" in the browser changes to contain the CSRF TOKEN + the arguments of the form (like in a GET request)

Comment: Can you check the form source code and see if the form is rendering correctly on the template? Make sure its method is post and url action is correctly rendering.

Comment: Checked the source; I have other forms in my project with identical template code and all working.

Comment: Thank you tons @Mohammad Golam Dostogir, the problem turned out to be malformed HTML. I tested my HTML code in https://validator.w3.org and it showed me duplicated form tags. Now the code works